# Is it possible to implement authentication based on string

Tags: laravel, security, authentication

Lets say I have a really basic authentication procedure where all you have to enter is the right security key. There are no such thing as a user table. All I want to check is, if the entered string matches my security key. Would that be possible to implement with laravel auth? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes it would be possible with laravel auth but it requires some changes to be made to the files you get when using the laravel auth.

Comment: You could just override the "login" method in the LoginController.php file and do your checks in there and then authenticate the user if the checks pass.

Comment: I'd still have to configure specific guards and stuff like that in my auth.php, wouldn't I? @user931018

Comment: @testoo Check my answer and see if it might work for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any persistent data like a database then you could use sessions. Override the login method in your LoginController and handle your check there.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if($request->input('security_key') === 'my_secret_string') {
        $request->session()->put('isAuthenticated', true);
        return redirect()->intended('success');
    }

    return back()->withErrors('Invalid secret key');
}
```

Then create a middleware to check if the user is authenticated. Let's call it check_auth:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!empty(session('isAuthenticated')) && session('isAuthenticated') === true) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

And in your routes add your middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'check_auth']], function () {
    //your routes here
});
```

And don't forget to add your new middleware to your `kernel.php` file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'check_auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\check_auth' //add this
    ];
```

Comment: No you shouldn't need a table since your Middleware takes care of the auth checking for you. Just apply the Middleware to each route you want the user to be authenticated to view. When the user logs out, just delete their session.

Comment: Because somehow it doesn't set the session, redirecting me always to '/login' .

Comment: @testoo Make sure that your `input` name in your view is the same as what you're expecting in your controller. I.e. if you have `input('security_key')` in your controller make sure that your input name in your view is also `name='security_key'`

Comment: I also forgot to mention that you must add your Middleware in your `kernel.php` file. See my updated answer.

Comment: I already did that. Same result. With or without ::class at the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200649/discussion-between-user931018-and-testoo).